# Tic-tac-toe possible grids

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-proofs, combinatorial-game-theory, tic-tac-toe

Let's consider the tic-tac-toe game, with two players and a natural number n of rows and columns (X starts; the winning player is the first who fills up a row, a column, the diagonal or the antidiagonal). Is it true that all the possible grids that may occur during the game are exactly those in which the difference between the X's and the O's is 0 or 1?

EDIT: Thanks to the helpful comments I've realised that that condition is necessary but not sufficient. Even so, is there any "easy" necessary and sufficient condition to establish whether a grid is a reachable game state?

Comment: I don't understand the question... Normally in tic-tac-toe the first player places their symbol onto the grid (1 more number of X's than O's), and then the second player places their symbol (Same number of X's than O's).  This repeats with the first player placing, then the second player placing and so on... forever alternating between having one more X than O's and then same number of X's than O's.  I should think this is obvious, no?  Or are you using some unusual ruleset?

Comment: If you really need formal proof of this, consider induction and cases

Comment: I find it obvious (and easily provable by induction) that all possible grids have that feature. But I wouldn't know how to prove that every grid which have that feature can be reachable in a game.

Comment: So you are asking if "Has 0 or 1 more X's than O's" is a necessary and sufficient condition for it to be a reachable gamestate?  Obviously not.  Consider $\begin{bmatrix}X&O&\\X&O&\\X&O&\end{bmatrix}$.  This gamestate is impossible as it should have ended before the final O was placed, despite there being the same number of X's as O's.  It is merely a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.  That is, unless you change the rules and allow play to continue even after a winner has been declared.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll update the question for a further clarification.

Comment: An easy necessary and sufficient condition for a gamestate to be reachable is for there to be an equal number of X's and O's or one more number of X's than O's, as well as there is at most one player with a winning row/column/diagonal such that if there is a winning player and it is the O player that there must be an equal number of X's and O's and further that if there is a winning player all winning rows/columns/diagonals if multiple must all share a single point.  For instance, $\begin{bmatrix}O&X&O\\X&&X\\O&X&O\end{bmatrix}$ could be the penultimate turn.

Comment: For sketch of a proof, if it ended with a win, remove that shared point (if single win, then any point).  That leaves you with a game state that can be reached by filling out the spaces in any desired order (*e.g. a greedy order*) and then as the final placement placing that winning move.  (*By a greedy order, I mean for example placing them alternating between X and O such that on a player's "turn" placing the in the "smallest" designated (non-final) space, "smallest" according to a lexicographic ordering of the positions*)

Comment: @RandomGuy broken link, and the more obvious search terms I would have thought of don't yield an answer to the specific question asked by OP.  "Necessary and sufficient conditions for player1 to have a winning strategy" is not the same question as "Necessary and sufficient conditions for a gamestate to be feasible"

Comment: ah link was working for me ill pull it down feasibility is a fun problem

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz for the valuable information.